# How do I download a .zip file from 000webhost with a button?

Tags: c#

I am trying to make my application have a button where I can press it for the latest version without having to download the newest version manually. It has to be my 000webhost because I need to be able to upload the new version to the same URL (if it was file dropper, or any other downloading/uploading sites, after uploading the same file twice, instead of being www.filedropper.com/File.zip it would be www.filedropper.com/File.zip_1). I hope you understand my paragraph.

```
    private void button17_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        WebClient update = new WebClient();
        try
        {
            update.DownloadFileAsync(new System.Uri("https://www.WEBSITENAME.000webhostapp.com/File.zip"), "File.zip");
        }
        catch (WebException ex4)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Either the download is not ready, the host is down, or your internet is bad/offline", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Hand);
        }
    }
```

I have tried this, it didn't seem to work. Do not laugh at me, please. I really suck at C# and have no major reason to learn it.

Comment: Why you say it's not working?

Answer (score 1):

It may be downloading the file to folder that you don't expect it to download to:

Create a folder `c:\temp` if it's not there already;

Change the code below to include specific folder:

```
update.DownloadFileAsync(new System.Uri("https://www.WEBSITENAME.000webhostapp.com/File.zip"),  @"c:\temp\File.zip");
```

After this try to find file in `C:\temp`

---

Update:

Hook `DownloadFileCompleted` event to get a signal when the file is ready for viewing.

```
update.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(Completed);

private void Completed(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
{
  Console.WriteLine("Download completed!");
}
```

Comment: It did download this time, but it says 0kb. "When I try to open it it says the archive is either in an unknown format or damaged."

Comment: Since it's async download, you either wait for the download to complete or hook DownloadFileCompleted event to signal you for completion then it will be not 0kb. Check updated code.